# web service using facebook authentication and android client

Tags: android, facebook

Our plan is to implement a web service using authentication from Facebook, we will have three instances: the web server, the facebook authentication server and the client. The web server can use the access_token to retrieve users' information on Facebook.

This works fine when the client is a web browser. Now, we want to implement the client on Android. We currently have two approaches:

1/ Create an Facebook Android native application, and use the Facebook Android SDK to get the access_token. The question for this approach is whether the obtained access_token can be passed to the web server, so that the web server can retrieve the users' information on Facebook?

2/ The second approach is to use the web browser on Android to authorize the web application and get back the access_token, then send this access_token to the web server for further action.

Please give us some advice if there are other approaches that we are missing. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 1. and pass the access token back to your server.

Comment: Hi @Ming Li, do you mean that the Web service and the Android native app can use the same access_token to retrieve information from Facebook. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want to post on the user's behalf, yes, the same access token can be used from anywhere. But the token will expire after a while, so your server will need to extend it at some point.